# Viewstate verification failed Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, viewstate

I'm having this error and I don't know what to do to identify the reason, I looked up Stackoverflow and checked web.config file and I don't have enableViewStateMac="false" at all.

```
        Event code: 4009  
        Event message: Viewstate verification failed. 
        Reason: The viewstate supplied failed integrity check.  
        Event time: 1/22/2019 2:53:36 PM  
        Event time (UTC): 1/22/2019 7:53:36 PM  
        Event ID: 5ffacfa116224c9f8f516ead8a89cc55  
        Event sequence: 378  
        Event occurrence: 1  
        Event detail code: 50203    
        Application information: 
        Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131926597583461452 
        Trust level: Full 
        Application Virtual Path: / 
        Application Path: ........... 
        Machine name: ..............    Process information: 
        Process ID: 6624 
        Process name: w3wp.exe 
        Account name: IIS APPPOOL\..............    Request information: 
        Request URL: ............../qConsole/CampaignGroup-Launch.aspx
        Request path: /qConsole/CampaignGroup-Launch.aspx 
        User host address: .............. 
        User:  
        Is authenticated: False 
        Authentication Type:  
        Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\..............
```

note: this is happening in every page, not only in a specific page, and more specifically when a page is making a call to the Db or making an SQL Bulk insert (2300 rows) or doing a long-time process like more than one minute.
I also double checked the machineKey tag in the web.config file, and it was not throwing any error before.

Comment: There  is a session timeout in WebForms, do you know the value?

Comment: Do I get it right that this only happens on requests that take some time (> 30 sec)?

Comment: @HenkHolterman how can I tell or check if this is happening ? what i'm currently doing: in the login page I'm generating a new sessionID if the user is authenticated (login page session X) rest of the site (session Y) is this might be the reason?